# What are the disadvantages when we opt for a lower dotnet version

Tags: .net

My dot net version is 4.5.1. I am using VS2013. Planning to do a project in dotnet version 3.5. What disadvantages are waiting for me when i do this?

Comment: Why do you plan a project in .NET 3.5? That's very relevant information here :)

Comment: You'll have to support users that for some reason refused to keep their machine updated.  By far the most troublesome users you'll ever run into, every support call is a potential nightmare that will take you days to recreate or debug their problem.  With many of them having nothing to do with your code but you have to support them anyway because nobody else will.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Why i am planning because, i want my program to run in xp too.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what Hans is talking about. And the truth is, are you really trying to sell a product to people who don't want to upgrade their OS? They don't tend to be the guys that like paying very much, and you're going to spend tons of effort on making sure you can support them. I'm not saying you can be sure it isn't worth it, but do give it due consideration.

Comment: No, this is a free tool. I want to make sure that xp users can use my program. And as i said in the below comment, if dot net is a problem, then i will do it in freeBasic.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to lack the features introduced in later versions of .NET. And .NET 4.5 isn't directly compatible with 3.5 by default, so you'll either need assembly binding redirects or your customers will need to have 3.5 installed.

Most libraries tend to target the latest versions of the runtime as well, so you'll have a lot less to choose from, or at the very least, you'll get a clunkier interface.

Answer (score 0):

You will lack any features added in the later versions (too many to list here). Some of those make programming certain things much simpler. However also note that newer operating systems may not have the older .Net versions installed by default.

In a couple of simple projects I did I kept the .Net version as low as possible, only increasing it if I needed features of higher versions. I was thinking that would keep it compatible with the most operating systems. Actually it meant that while it worked on older systems users on newer ones had to specifically install the older .Net version to run my program.

I tend to aim for at least 4.0 for that reason.

Comment: Thanks RosieC. This move is due to compatibility issues. My another option is to do this project in freeBasic. In that case i will miss the state of the art IDE support but will gain more power.